# Checking if a post is spam

Tags: support, spam

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1543168/272824) links to the author's site.

It is a poor answer, and could only be used in conjunction with the author's site as a vital detail (what the "program" is) is missing.

Does

> Thanks BuildSomeTech

count as disclosing the author's affiliation?

Comment: I can't comment on the actual answer, because it's deleted and I can't see it. However, disclosure of affiliation must be explicit, but doesn't need to be formal. Just something like "I wrote", "on my site/blog", etc. is sufficient. It is not sufficient to require a reader to match a link or domain to the author's username. The "Thanks" which you include in the question here does not count as disclosure of affiliation.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks, I guess someone else decided it really was spam, hence the deletion.

Comment: The "thanks Name" shouldn't be in questions or answers and is likely to be deleted anyway. It certainly doesn't count as a declaration of affiliation, or of ownership of the linked resource.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks. It didn't look right to me, but it's good to get confirmation from a moderator. I can't tell nowadays if editing out "thanks" is regarded as being unkind to new users, but that's a different matter.

Comment: The answer was deleted by spam by the community user.  This means enough users flagged it as spam for that to happen.

Comment: @Ramhound Moderators use the spam-flag method the same as other users, but in our case the flag is immediately considered to hit the threshold for community user deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it is worth, *I* saw it and decided that the "my name is the same as the blog" didn't count as *enough* disclosure. On top of that our [spam rules](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) also prefer that posts pointing to your own blog should not be your *only* contribution to the site.

> Post good, relevant answers, and if some (**but not all**) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay.

If it were a long answer that had some reason to clarify side details that were not necessary to "complete" the answer then a blog post *might* be relevant. But in this case all the detail *should* have been held on our site which, sadly, it was not.

Upon reading (and rereading) the answer 90% of it was fluffy blog post preamble, talking to other users and the remainder was incomplete. In particular the answer stated "Download and Install the Program" without stating what program, indicating that it was copy-pasted from their site (oddly if they *had* don't that then it would have stood on its own) and a visit would be required in order to either fix the answer or find out what program. The answer did not appear to be a genuine attempt to fit in with the site or help OP, but instead was a vehicle to promote their blog.

> Hi @JOURNEYMAN & @Scott
>
> How to make an ISO file out of a folder containing Windows setup
>   files?
>
> And the answer to this question is pretty simple and easy if you
>   follow these simple steps. Here I will show you how you can easily
>   convert the windows extracted files to an iso image file. This post
>   also helped me a lot in creating the my iso file from windows copied
>   files... I have used this method to create different ISO files like
>   Windows Xp,7,8,10.
>
> And hope this post will definitely help you...
>
> Just follow these simple steps
>
> 1. Download and Install the Program.
> 2. Select Windows Installation Files.
> 3. Make bootable ISO.
> 4. Configure the ISO file.
> 5. Done! For detailed post Visit the given [link]. (link removed)
>
> Please Upvote & Share.
>
> Thanks BuildSomeTech